# Why is my implementation of the Sieve of Atkin overlooking numbers close to the specified limit?

Tags: python, math, primes, sieve-of-atkin

My implementation of [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) either overlooks primes near the limit or composites near the limit. while some limits work and others don't. I'm am completely confused as to what is wrong.

```
def AtkinSieve (limit):
results = [2,3,5]
sieve = [False]*limit
factor = int(math.sqrt(lim))
for i in range(1,factor):
    for j in range(1, factor):
        n = 4*i**2+j**2
        if (n <= lim) and (n % 12 == 1 or n % 12 == 5):
            sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
        n = 3*i**2+j**2
        if (n <= lim) and (n % 12 == 7):
            sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
        if i>j:
            n = 3*i**2-j**2
            if (n <= lim) and (n % 12 == 11):
                sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
for index in range(5,factor):
    if sieve[index]:
        for jndex in range(index**2, limit, index**2):
            sieve[jndex] = False
for index in range(7,limit):
    if sieve[index]:
        results.append(index)
return results
```

For example, when I generate a primes  to the limit of 1000, the Atkin sieve misses the prime 997, but includes the composite 965. But if I generate up the limit of 5000, the list it returns is completely correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Change `lim` to `limit`. Of course you must have known that.

  Since `sieve = [False]*limit`,
  the largest index allowed is `limit-1`.

However, on this line

```
if (n <= limit) and (n % 12 == 1 or n % 12 == 5):
```

you are checking if `n<=limit`. If `n==limit` then `sieve[n]` raises an IndexError.
Try your algorithm with a small value of `limit` (e.g. n=50). You'll see this error come up.
An easy fix is to use

```
sieve = [False]*(limit+1)
```

The easy fix is a bit wasteful since sieve[0] is never used. So you might think a better fix is to keep `sieve = [False]*limit`, but fix all your other code by stepping the index on `sieve` down by one. (E.g., change `sieve[n]` to `sieve[n-1]` everywhere, etc.) However, this will force you to do a number of extra subtractions which will not be good for speed. So the easy/wasteful solution is actually probably the better option.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin,
x should be an integer in [1,sqrt(limit)], inclusive of the endpoints.

In your code

```
factor = int(math.sqrt(limit))
```

and `int` takes the *floor* of `math.sqrt(limit)`.  Furthermore,

`range(1,factor)` goes from 1 to factor-1. So you are off by 1.

So you need to change this to

```
factor = int(math.sqrt(limit))+1
```

See [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/2068548#2068548) for an alternative (and faster) implementation of the Sieve of Atkin, due to Steve Krenzel.

```
def AtkinSieve (limit):
    results = [2,3,5]
    sieve = [False]*(limit+1)
    factor = int(math.sqrt(limit))+1
    for i in range(1,factor):
        for j in range(1, factor):
            n = 4*i**2+j**2
            if (n <= limit) and (n % 12 == 1 or n % 12 == 5):
                sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
            n = 3*i**2+j**2
            if (n <= limit) and (n % 12 == 7):
                sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
            if i>j:
                n = 3*i**2-j**2
                if (n <= limit) and (n % 12 == 11):
                    sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
    for index in range(5,factor):
        if sieve[index]:
            for jndex in range(index**2, limit, index**2):
                sieve[jndex] = False
    for index in range(7,limit):
        if sieve[index]:
            results.append(index)
    return results
```

Comment: Yeah after programming in Java i noticed all these mistakes... I will definitely check out that faster implementation though.